# Change the forms/upload.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I would like to customize the forms/upload.aspx so that I can include a hyperlink to another application which automatically populates the name field in upload.aspx.Then I would like to populate the same data in edit form.aspx.Is this feasible. Please let me know if I need to provide any further information.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post additional information of specifically what u want done (with an example) and any code you have so far?

Comment: I would like to edit the upload.aspx page in forms folder. Is there any way I can achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Browse to the Document Library inside SharePoint Designer. Under the Forms section, you can open up Upload.aspx or EditForm.aspx and make your changes.